# Dygraphs: Highlight specific point on mouse over

Tags: javascript, charts, dygraphs

Is there a way to highlight a specific point when mouse is over or near that specific point ? The thing is that I don't want to highlight all the lines but only the point(s) under or near my cursor. My goal is to show a tooltip at that position with the informations for that point.

This ChartJs example demonstrate pretty well what I would like to do:
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html

And these are my current options:

```
{
    drawPoints: true,
    showRoller: false,
    highlightCircleSize: 5,
    labels: ['Time', 'Vac', 'Temp'],
    ylabel: 'Vaccum (In/Hg)',
    y2label: 'Temperature ('+ TemperatureUnitFactory.getTemperatureUnit() + ')',
    series : {
        'Vac': {
          axis: 'y'
        },
        'Temp': {
          axis: 'y2'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        y: {
            drawGrid: true,
            independentTicks: true,
            valueRange: [0, -32],
            label: 'Vaccum'
        },
        y2: {
            drawGrid: false,
            independentTicks: true,
            valueRange: [
                TemperatureUnitFactory.getTemperatureForUnit(-30),
                TemperatureUnitFactory.getTemperatureForUnit(35)
            ],
            ylabel: 'Temperature'
        }
    }
}
```

If you feel like I am missing informations that would help you enlighting me, just let me know in a comment.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think i've found a solution to my problem. I will come with a complete answer next week.

Comment: Did you ever end up documenting your solution?

Comment: @krsmith88 Just updated my post with an answer. Let me know if this help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a snippet for the solution to my problem. I believe it could be optimized by throtling the mousemouve callback, but in my case it did just fine. I converted the snippet from angular to jQuery for "simplicity".

```js
var data = [
  [new Date(20070101),62,39],
  [new Date(20070102),62,44],
  [new Date(20070103),62,42],
  [new Date(20070104),57,45],
  [new Date(20070105),54,44],
  [new Date(20070106),55,36],
  [new Date(20070107),62,45],
  [new Date(20070108),66,48],
  [new Date(20070109),63,39],
  [new Date(20070110),57,37],
  [new Date(20070111),50,37],
  [new Date(20070112),48,35],
];

var graph = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("chart"), data, {
    rollPeriod: 1,
    labels: ['Time', 'Vac', 'Temp'],
    showRoller: false,
    drawPoints: true,
  }
);

var tooltip = {
 element: $('#tooltip'),
  x: function(_x){
   this.element.css('left', _x);
  },
 y: function(_y) {
   this.element.css('top', _y);
  },
 shown: false,
 throttle: null,
 currentPointData: null,
 show: function() {
  if(!this.shown) {
   this.element.show();
      this.shown = true;
  }
 },
 hide: function() {
  this.cancelThrottle();
  if(this.shown) {
   this.element.hide();
      this.shown = false;
  }
 },
 cancelThrottle: function () {
  if(this.throttle !== null) {
   clearTimeout(this.throttle);
   this.throttle = null;
  }
 },
 bindPoint: function (_point) {
   this.element.html([_point.point.name,_point.point.xval, _point.point.yval].join(' | '))
  console.log('Handle point data', _point);
 }
};

var chartElement = $('#chart');
var isMouseDown = false;

chartElement.on('mousedown', function(){ isMouseDown = true; });
chartElement.on('mouseup', function(){ isMouseDown = false; });

chartElement.on('mousemove', function(){
 if(graph === null) { return; }

  if(isMouseDown) {
    tooltip.hide();
    return;
  }

  const ACCEPTABLE_OFFSET_RANGE = 8;
  const TOOLTIP_BOTTOM_OFFSET = 25;
  const TOOLTIP_THROTTLE_DELAY = 600;

  var graphPos = Dygraph.findPos(graph.graphDiv),
    canvasX = Dygraph.pageX(event) - graphPos.x,
    canvasY = Dygraph.pageY(event) - graphPos.y,
    rows = graph.numRows(),
    cols = graph.numColumns(),
    axes = graph.numAxes(),
    diffX, diffY, xPos, yPos, inputTime, row, col, axe;

  for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
  {
    inputTime = graph.getValue(row, 0);
    xPos = graph.toDomCoords(inputTime, null)[0];
    diffX = Math.abs(canvasX - xPos);

    if (diffX < ACCEPTABLE_OFFSET_RANGE)
    {
      for (col = 1; col < cols; col++)
      {
        var inputValue = graph.getValue(row, col);
        if (inputValue === null) { continue; }

        for(axe = 0; axe < axes; axe++)
        {
          yPos = graph.toDomCoords(null, inputValue, axe)[1];
          diffY = Math.abs(canvasY - yPos);

          if (diffY < ACCEPTABLE_OFFSET_RANGE)
          {
            tooltip.cancelThrottle();

            if(!tooltip.shown)
            {
              var self = this;

              tooltip.throttle = setTimeout(function () {
                var ttHeight = tooltip.element.height(),
          ttWidth = tooltip.element.width();
                tooltip.x((xPos - (ttWidth / 2)));
                tooltip.y((yPos - (ttHeight + TOOLTIP_BOTTOM_OFFSET)));
                tooltip.show();

                var closestPoint = graph.findClosestPoint(xPos, yPos);
                if(closestPoint) {
                  tooltip.bindPoint(closestPoint);
                }

              }, TOOLTIP_THROTTLE_DELAY);

            }

            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  tooltip.hide();
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position:relative;
}

.chart-container > .tooltip {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color:#ababab;
  color:#fff;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">
    Some data to be shown
  </div>
</div>
```